# Joomla 2.5 Smart Search - search as exact phrase by default

Tags: joomla-2.5, smartsearch

How can I set Smart Search to search as exact phrase by default? I've noticed that most of our users expect "exact phrase" behaviour rather than "this AND that" behaviour when they type into the Smart Search module, and are disappointed by the results.

For example, when a user types the following into the search box:

> freedom of speech

what they actually mean (but never actually type) is:

> "freedom of speech"

They are then disappointed by results that contain the words "freedom", "of" and "speech" individually. I would like to set Smart Search to "exact phrase" behaviour by default.

Does anyone have ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using an associated menu item for the Search Results?  If so, you should be able to go on the OPTIONS tab and change the "Search For" to "Exact Phrase."  If using the module, make sure you set the "Set ItemID" to that menu item.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, YellowWebMonkey. I either don't have this "Search for" option or I don't know where to find it. I have gone to Components > Smart Search, then clicked the "Options" button. The configuration options that appear do not include "Search for". [Here's a screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/6u7qxer7v/) — would you mind having a look and confirming if I'm in the right spot? Many thanks.

Comment: It is within the menu item.  If you do not have one, you need to make one: http://goo.gl/fRUQXU.  Within that, you change the SEARCH FOR: http://goo.gl/78WJi8.   You probably want to make a new menu to put this on since you do not want it to show on your main navigation.  My general practice is to make a menu named "System" with links like search, login, sitemap, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots, YellowWebMonkey. I see now that your menu item is of type "Seach > Search form or search results" (mine is "Smart Search > Search"). I think perhaps you're using default Search, not Smart Search (which is [not enabled by default in Joomla 2.5](https://docs.joomla.org/Smart_Search_quickstart_guide)). It would appear that default search is com_search and Smart Search is com_finder. At any rate, I tried out "Search form or search results" with exact phrase, and it was returning pages that didn't contain the search phrase _at all_. I might just have to give up :(

Comment: If you are willing to use something besides Smart Search, I have done something similar in MijoSearch by hacking administrator/components/com_mijosearch/library/search.php and modifying the types of searches in function getSearchQuery()

Comment: Thanks for MijoSearch rec. How would you rate its "exact phrase" function? I had a look at the demo site, and [searching for the exact phrase "It is a great way"](http://demo.miwisoft.com/joomla/mijosearch?order=relevance&query=It+is+a+great+way) produces no results even though the phrase occurs in the page [MijoSEF - Joomla SEO & SEF](http://demo.miwisoft.com/joomla/components/mijosef-joomla-seo-sef), which surprised me.

Comment: I am not in love with MijoSearch but needed it for a particular product.  In the file I mentioned, I made a tweak at the end of the getSearchQuery() before the return to add % on either side of the exact phrase.  The way it is currently coded, the search phrase has to be an exact match to the description (or whatever) rather than containing that search phrase.  A bit of a hack but easier than re-writing their whole query.

Comment: You may not know the answer to this, but do you have to index the content with MijoSearch or does it perform a search on the full description (or whatever) every time?